# Providing liferay user id into orbeon form runner generated xml

Tags: java, liferay, orbeon

I make portal based on Liferay, which has funcionality associated with Orbeon. I run Orbeon form runner inside html frame and I want to insert some extra data like Liferay-User-Id into xml generated by filled form. Is there some possibility to make that or other idea that helps me provide, user's id who filled form, to database?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Orbeon Forms 4.4, the Liferay proxy portlet [allows you to propagate user information as headers](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/form-runner-proxy-portlet-guide#TOC-Configure-the-proxy-portlet). This is possible because the portlet has access to Liferay user information.

From within an iframe, it's a different story. If you manage to set URL parameters, then you can retrieve them from your form with the `xxf:get-request-parameter()` function.

Comment: Thank You. I changed my mind, and I do not want to use iframe. Now I use simple link to Form Runner, but there is appear next problem, because I do not want to use get parameter, because someone can pretend to be someone else and use his user-id. I know, that there is get-session-attribute, but I do not have access to Orbeon session. Is there any possibility to fix that, without PE?

Comment: The second idea is to code the user's id and decode it in xforms, using key. Is there possibility like that ?

Comment: In general I wouldn't recommend doing that, because odds are that the encryption will somehow provide a false sense of security and in fact have a weakness somewhere. It's better to use a completely opaque random key, and to have a mapping with the data done safely on the server, much like session cookies and session data are usually handled.